# Write value back to function parameters

Tags: c#

When you pass a parameter to a function, you can "overwrite" that parameter by using the keyword ref. However, that only works until the function reaches its end. After that the parameter source is forgotten by the class.

What I have tried is: I have created a list-member in my `Class2` so that I can store the list-parameter that is sent by `Class1`. Then I make changes to my list-member in `Class2`, but can't figure out a way to update (resend) the changes to the list in `Class1`.

**Class2**

```
public ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

public void ReceiveMessage(ObservableCollection<Message> list)
{
    messages = list;
}
```

**Make changes to** *messages*...

```
//A method that writes back to list in Class1
//You guys' answers comes here
```

**Class1**

```
public ObservableCollection<Message> list = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

Class2.ReceiveMessage(list);
```

My question is, how do I update the list in `Class1` from the method in `Class2`?

Comment: As it is currently written, it's hard to tell what your question is. Please clarify it.

Comment: `Class2.ReceiveMessage` receives reference of `list`. After calling it `list` is getting modified inside `Class1`

Comment: @NahuelIanni I have updated the post with a clear question.

Comment: @GeneR That's right, but I would like to be able to modify my `Class1`-list by using an "update"-function from `Class2`.

Comment: do yo mean `Class2.ReceiveMessage(Class1.list)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `messages` as a public property, so you can access it in any other class

```
public class Class2
{
    public ObservableCollection<Message> messages {get;set;}

    public void ReceiveMessage(ObservableCollection<Message> list)
    {
        messages = list;
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    ...
    ObservableCollection<Message> list = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

    Class2.ReceiveMessage(list);

    var updatedList = Class2.message;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear about that part, they are already public in my code. I edited it in the post.

Comment: The equal operator (=) will assign the variable pointer to another memory zone (instance) so you need to avoid that operator, use .Clear(), .Add() methods instead. Otherwise, you need to re-assign the variable like my solution.